# Quantum oscillator; find $E$ (time ind)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

ok so everything I've looked at shows how to derive $E$ for the ground state, but usually in exams my teacher gives the wave function in some excited state normalized or not, and asks to find $E$ and which state its at.
So example:

$$
\psi(x)=A(2m\omega x^2-\hbar)e^{-(m\omega x^2)/2\hbar}
$$

I derivate $\psi$ two times and substitute that to the time ind. eq.
let $a=m\omega$, $b=$ the exp

$$
Ab\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{(2a^3x^4)}{\hbar^2}\right) +\left(\frac{(-11a^2x^2)}{\hbar})+5a\right)=(E-V)(2ax^2-\hbar)Ab \tag{1}
$$

the $Ab$ cancels out

T know $V=0.5m(\omega x)^2$, and I have the solution to the problem so I know the derivative is correct and that $E=(5/2)\hbar \omega$ but I have no idea how to get here

Basically i just need to know what to do next; in the solutions, where I have $(E-V)$ they have $(ax^2-5\hbar)$ and I dont know where that comes from. I tried setting the "no $x$" term = $E$ ; and the "$x^2$ term" = $V$ that got:

$$
E=(5/2) \omega \hbar^2 ~~~~~~~~\mbox{(close)}
$$

$$
V= (-11/2) m\hbar(\omega x)^2 ~~~~~~~~\mbox{(also close)}
$$

but this isn't correct

---

**EDIT**

ok I have something new, if I solve the second side of eq.1 I get:
$2Eax^2-\hbar E$ and $-2Vax^2+\hbar V$; and I set

$\hbar E=$"no x term"

and

$-2Vax^2=$"the $x^4$ term"

I get the correct results, help me understand this please

Comment: This is very difficult to read... I would be very useful if you could properly typeset your question.

Comment: i know it is, how do i typeset it?

Comment: Here is good reference https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: im fixing it now

Comment: i think its acceptable now @ZeroTheHero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the algebra by a lot if you call

$$
y = \alpha x = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x
$$

In this case, the wave function

$$
\psi(x) = Ce^{-\alpha^2x^2/2} (2\alpha^2x^2 - 1)
$$

becomes

$$
\psi(y) = Ce^{-y^2/2}(2y^2 - 1) \tag{1}
$$

And Schrodinger's equation takes the form

\begin{eqnarray}
H\psi &=& -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} +\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2 \psi\\
&=&-\frac{\hbar^2\alpha^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dy^2} +\frac{m\omega^2}{2\alpha^2}y^2 \psi \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega\left(-\frac{d^2\psi}{dy^2} + y^2\psi\right) = 5\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}\psi(y)
\end{eqnarray}

Thefore

$$
E = \frac{5}{2}\hbar\omega \tag{2}
$$

Comment: i can follow evryting up until $$\frac{1}{2}ℏω(−\frac{d^2ψ}{dy^2}+y^2ψ)$$, what do you after? you substitute the function and the second derivative into that?

Comment: @wrong1man Replace the value of $\alpha^2 = m\omega/\hbar$ and simplify, most of the terms cancel out

Comment: @wrong1man Yes! Substitute and factor back $\psi$

Comment: ohhhhh i go it... i disregarded my teacher when he wrote the derivatives w.r.t the original function which i see now makes it all SO much easier! thank you!